# Python code to Java code conversion

Tags: java, python, recursion, backtracking

I wrote some code in python that works really well and I was trying to implement it in Java and I am having some slight troubles. It is a simple 21 question using backtracking that takes a string input from the user such as " 1 9 10"

Here is the python code:

```
def twentyone(nums, stack = [], answer = set()):
    for index, num in enumerate(nums):
        new_stack = stack + [num]
        total = sum(new_stack)
        if total == 21:
            answer.add(tuple(new_stack))
        elif total < 21:
            twentyone(nums[index + 1:], new_stack, answer)
    return answer

user_input = input()
list_format = [int(x) for x in user_input.split()]
answer = twentyone(list_format)

if len(answer) == 0:
    print("No combination of numbers add to 21")
for solution in answer:
    print("The values ", end = "")
    for number in solution:
            print("{} ".format(number), end = "")
    print("add up to 21")
```

and here is my java code (so far)

```
public class TwentyOne {

   public static void main(String args[]){
      Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
      String stringInput = userInput.nextLine();

      ArrayList<Integer> allNum = new ArrayList<>();
      for (String num : stringInput.split(" ")){
         allNum.add(Integer.parseInt(num));
      }

      HashSet<ArrayList<Integer>> answer = twentyOne(allNum);

      for (ArrayList<Integer> solution : answer){
         System.out.print("The values ");
         for (Integer num : solution){
            System.out.print(num + " ");
         }
         System.out.println("Add up to 21");
      }
   }



   private static HashSet twentyOne(ArrayList<Integer> user_input){

      return new HashSet<ArrayList<Integer>>();
   }
}
```

Basically, I cant get around writing java recursion problems without variable initialization in the parameters.

i.e     `def twentyone(nums, stack = [], answer = set()):`

So my question is, how do I deal with java backtracking without variable initialization within the method I will be doing the recursive calls on?

Comment: What's the problem? Initialize them before calling the function?

Comment: But if I declare a stack before the function call and make it an object attribute, in each recursive instance wouldnt the stack be the same? I need each stack in each recursive call to be different.
Maybe I've done too much python, could you make tell me what In my java code for it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would write a wrapper method that passes the default arguments. e.g.:

```
twentyone(List<Integer> nums) {
    twentyoneRecursive(nums, new ArrayDeque<>(), new HashSet<>());
}

twentyoneRecursive(List<Integer> nums, Deque<Integer> stack, Set<List<Integer>> answer) {
    ...
    twentyoneRecursive(...);
}
```

Comment: Haven't seen a Deque<Integer> before, I'll have to look into that but this looks like a promising method thanks :D

Comment: @user7404408 Regarding your comment above, I haven't done _too_ much python, but I think calling `stack + [num]` as well as `nums[index + 1:]` creates copies of those lists. While Java doesn't have operator overloading and just has the equivalent of `list.append`. For the latter case you could use [`List.subList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-), since you're only reading from it. But for the stack case, you'd have to create a copy and then do the adding operation.

Comment: Update: Completed, here is the link to my result.
https://github.com/AmbushSta/javaProjects/blob/master/21UsingRecursion.java
Thanks for your help.